# Como obtener el valor registrado en el Combobox - Angular

Tags: angular

Hola Buenas quisiera que me puedan ayudar, tengo un formulario que al momento de editar ya salga el combo seleccionado que se guardo.

```
<form [formGroup]="itemForm" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
 <mat-form-field class="full-width">
          <mat-label>{{HDESAGE.label}}</mat-label>
              <mat-select formControlName="HDESAGE">
                      <mat-option  *ngFor="let r of HDESAGE.data" [value]="r.id" >{{r.desc}}</mat-option>
                  </mat-select>
                  <mat-error *ngIf="itemForm.get('HDESAGE').hasError('required')">
                    Ingrese la agencia
                  </mat-error>
      </mat-form-field>  
</form>
```

He intentado con Get segun la documentación pero nada
export class TransaccionPopupComponent implements OnInit {
public itemForm: FormGroup;

```
HDESAGE:any={
     //label:'Seleccione la agencia:',
     selected:null,
     hidden:true,
     variable:'HDESAGE',
     data:[
     ]
   }

ngOnInit() {
    this.renderSlcAgencia();
    this.buildItemForm(this.data.data1)
    
  }

buildItemForm(item) {
     
    this.itemForm = this.fb.group({
       
      HDESAGE: new FormControl({  value: [item.HDESAGE || '',Validators.required], disabled: false }),
       
    })

    console.log(this.agenciaF);
    console.log(this.itemForm.controls.HDESAGE.get('0').value)
    this.agenciaF.valueChanges
    .subscribe((r)=>{
       let ciu=this.itemForm.controls.HDESAGE.get('0').value;
      this.itemForm.controls.HDESAGE.get('0').setValue([ciu]);
      console.log(ciu);
       
    })
 
  }

   get agenciaF(){ 
    let respuesta = this.itemForm.controls.HDESAGE as FormControl 
    console.log(respuesta); 
    return respuesta
  }

// Aca me devuelve la lista de agencia que se llena en el combobox
private renderSlcAgencia(): void {
    let report = 'SEL_JER_01';
    this.cs.getRegularData(report, {}).subscribe(
      (data) => {
        let result = data.body['result'];
        this.dynamic_ciiu=result.body;  
        this.HDESAGE.data=this.dynamic_ciiu.filter(d=>d.sec_eco=="Agencia")
         
      })
  }

}
```

Al momento de ejecutar en el combo sale vacio y cuando despliego sale toda la lista que viene de la bd pero yo quiero que cuando inicie salga el valor que se guardo y despues ya la lista

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Buenos la solución era colocar en el initform el valor y para eso realice la propiedad setValue

```
 this.itemForm.controls.HDESAGE.setValue(item.HDESAGE)
```